# Is it possible to raise undead versions of animals (or other creatures)?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, animals, necromancy

**Are there any ways to make undead animals in D&D 5e?**

What other types of creatures can be raised from the dead except humanoids, and how can this be achieved?

I'm interested in ways to do so, both as a player and as a DM. Spells are preferred, as they are more easily available, but any kind of way to do this is OK. Both temporary and permanent solutions are acceptable.

Comment: Are you just interested in taking a dead animal and raising it as any kind of undead? Or are you specifically asking whether there is, e.g., a way to create an undead horse (with its own statblock distinct from the general zombie/skeleton/etc. statblock)?

Comment: I am interested in creating undead from any species of livestock, wild animals and pets (cats, dogs). The possibility of the animal to have another (more relevant) stats in undead form is also interesting. Lack of official templates for dnd 5e is very sad. So this question is also about what possibilities exist for creating stat blocks of creatures in this case.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

Two examples would be the spells [Negative Energy Flood](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/negative-energy-flood) (XGtE, p. 163) and [Danse Macabre](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/danse-macabre) (XGtE, p. 153).

If a creature is killed by the damage from Negative Energy Flood, the target will rise as a zombie. Danse Macabre will raise up to 5 Small or Medium corpses as either zombies or skeletons (your choice).

Note that in both cases, the stats of the undead creatures are those of [zombies](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/zombie)/[skeletons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/skeleton) as stated.