# Can a tarrasque be animated by negative energy flood?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, undead

The spell *negative energy flood* says:

> "You send ribbons of negative energy at one creature you can see within range. Unless the target is undead, it must make a Constitution saving throw, taking 5d12 necrotic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. A target killed by this damage rises up as a zombie at the start of your next turn. The zombie pursues whatever creature it can see that is closest to it. Statistics for the zombie are in the Monster Manual. If you target an undead with this spell, the target doesn’t make a saving throw. Instead, roll 5d12. The target gains half the total as temporary hit points"

It does not specify the creature must be humanoid nor the size of the creature. However, it implies the new zombie's stats must be in the MM. Can a tarrasque be animated by this spell's effect?

Comment: Related, possible dupes: [Does a size large or larger creature killed by Negative Energy Flood rise as a medium sized zombie?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/170530), [Is it possible to raise undead versions of animals (or other creatures)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171448)

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Actually, yeah. This appears to be fully covered by that other question, so I've marked it as such. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.